# Is there a way to switch server context within a t-sql script?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I will need to add several new developers to some SQL-Server database servers in the next month.  I want to create a template script to save some time and avoid mistakes.  Is it possible to change the database server context in SQL Server script?

Example:

```sql
USE [SqlServer1]
GO
CREATE USER [domain\username] FOR LOGIN [domain\username]
GO

USE [DBServer2]
GO
CREATE USER [domain\username] FOR LOGIN [domain\username]
GO

etc...
```

Comment: you can create stored procedure with dynamic SQL. Then you can pass user/domain to that stored procedure. Example EXEC('CREATE USER ['+@domain+'\'+@username+'] FOR LOGIN ['+@domain+'\'+@username+'])'

Comment: Short answer - no. A script, by itself, has no real concept of a "current" server instance since that is determined by the connection which is established outside of the script. [Granting permissons using AD groups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/how-do-i-assign-an-entire-active-directory-group-security-access-in-sql-server-2) might be a far simpler solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want create batch file that would help you to connect different servers in the context of `sqlcmd`, you would use `:connect [Servername]` multiple time within batch file, [for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-2017)